# How To Join Multiple array String Into single Array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have array from json:

```
var list = ["one"],["two"],["three"]
```

how to join them to become `["one","two","three"]

I'm using dropdown from this https://github.com/jriosdev/iOSDropDown

it needs to be :

// The list of array to display. Can be changed dynamically.

```
trfBankTujuan.optionArray = ["nama 1", "nama 2", "nama 3", "nama 4"]
```

i want to fill those list of array from JSON:

```
"data_transaction": [
        {
            "kode": "002",
            "nama": "nama 1"
        },
        {
            "kode": "011",
            "nama": "nama 2"
        },
        {
            "kode": "008",
            "nama": "nama 3"
        },
        {
            "kode": "009",
            "nama": "nama 4"
        }
]
```

---

```
var banknya: String = ""

class APITrf: NSObject {

class func BankList(completion: @escaping (_ error: Error?, _ banklikst: [Bank]?)->Void) {

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
                .responseJSON { response in

                    switch response.result
                    {
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)

                    case .success(let value):
                        let json = JSON(value)
                        print(json)

                        if let status = json["status"].string {
                            if (json["status"] == "00") {
                                print("status: \(status)" + " = sukses")
                                let dataBank = json["data_transaction"].array

                            }
                        } else {
                            if (json["status"] != "00") {
                                print("must return to login screen")
                            }
                        }
    for (index,subJson):(String, JSON) in json["data_transaction"] {

                            if let nama_Bank = subJson["nama_bank"].string {

                                banknya = nama_Bank
                                print(banknya)


                            }
                        }
```

Then i want to put those object "banknya" into :

```
import UIKit
import iOSDropDown

class AB: UIViewController {

   func dropDownBankList() {
      trfBankTujuan.optionArray = [banknya]
   }

}
```

Comment: i think OP needs flattened array rather than " Join  multiple array" , since he is declaring it as one variable .

Comment: @MohmmadS: And that has been asked and answered as well – I have added another link to the duplicate targets.

Comment: @MartinR  sure master, I just thought the appending is not what he needed

Answer (score 2):

Considering the right format of `list`

you can use `flatMap`

```
 var list = [["one"],["two"],["three"]] 
 var flatted = list.flatMap{ $0 } // result : ["one", "two", "three"]
```

Comment: but i want to make it to be list = ["one","two","three"] not list = [["one"],["two"],["three"]]

Comment: `var flatted = list.flatMap{ $0 }` // would make it what you want use it in playground and check the result of flatted

Comment: i got this error message "Cannot assign value of type '[Character]' to type '[String]'"

Comment: @flozgaillard: It would help if you post valid code in your question. `var list = ["one"],["two"],["three"]` does not compile.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using

*flatmap*

```
var theResult = list.flatMap {$0}
```

*reduce*

```
var theResult = list.reduce([String](), { result, item in
    return result + item.reduce([String](), { $0 + [$1] })
})
```

*forEach* <- worst solution

```
var theResult = [String]()
list.forEach { item in
    item.forEach { subItem in
        theResult.append(subItem)
    }
}
```